# Generic foreign key in Django showing error must be instance of Content Type

Tags: django, django-generic-relations

I have a following abstract Class

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now 2 classes inherit from above:-

```
class Car(Manufacturer):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Bike(Manufacturer):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Now I want to link them with features, so I create following classes:-

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    limit=models.Q(model = 'car') | models.Q(model = 'bike')
    features = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType, through='Mapping',limit_choices_to=limit)

class Mapping(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    limit=models.Q(model = 'car') | models.Q(model = 'bike')
    content = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to=limit,default='')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    contentObject = GenericForeignKey('content', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('category', 'content','object_id'),)
        db_table = 'wl_categorycars'
```

But When i try creating instances in shell commands I get an error while creating mapping instance

> **"Mapping.content" must be a "ContentType" instance.**

```
car1=Car(company="ducati",name="newcar")
bike1=Bike(company="bike",name="newbike")

cat1=Category(name="speed")

mapping(category=cat1, content=car1)  # ---> i get error at this point
```

How do I proceed with this?

Comment: Try to understand this code and you will know it. from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.tag

Comment: I did go through the documentation, but when using unique_together i cannot put contentObject as such in the model, it throws error saying multiple table inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your object with:

```
Mapping(
   category=cat1,
   content=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(car1),
   object_id=car.id
)
```

By the way, I would have named the field `content_type` instead of `content` to avoid ambuiguity. See the [official documentation for more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use `contentObject` parameter for populating model objects as GenericForeignKey instead of `content`.

Something like this should work:

`Mapping(category=cat1, contentObject=car1)`